# Erro na realização do insert no oracle

Tags: sql, sql-insert

Estou com problemas para realizar o insert numa tabela chamada contas, entretanto eu tenho relacionamento com a tabela empresa.

Na tabela empresa eu tenho o seguintes campos:

```
Id_empresa | Nome_Empresa | Inscricao_Estadual.

255        | AMG Ltda     | 08522255
```

Já na tabela de contas eu possuo o seguintes campos:

```
Id_contas | Id_Empresa | Valor | Inscricao_Estadual | Ano_Mes | Ano_Mes_Conta | ICMS | TOTAL_RECOLHIDO
```

Porém, para realizar o `insert` eu tenho que verificar se a inscrição estadual que estou inserido existe na tabela de empresa, se existir eu insiro, caso não existe retorna o erro de inserção.

Eu não sei se existe a possibilidade de fazer no `select` as que não existir não inserir e no final mostrar essas inscrições estadual que não tenha vinculo com nenhuma empresa no banco de dados. Como poderia ser tratado o erro que estou recebendo e essa validação?

```
    INSERT INTO Contas(
    id_Conta,
    id_empresa,
    valor,
    inscricao_estadual,
    ano_mes,
    ano_mes_Conta,
    icms,
    total_recolhido)
    VALUES(
    365545,
    '25.300,38',
    '08522255',
    (SELECT emp.id_empresa FROM EMPRESA emp  where emp.Inscricao_Estadual = '08522255'),
    '199810',
    '199910',
    '38.011,71',
    '38.011,71');
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

> Relatório de erros -
>   ORA-01722: número inválido

Se alguém puder me ajudar, fico agradecido.

Comment: no campo inscricao_estadual, você quer inserir o id da empresa, da tabela de empresas ? (mas esse não parece ser o problema) => Número inválido deve ser os campos numéricos que estão com . e ,. O normal é que nos bancos o separador decimal é o . então o formato do número está incorreto

Comment: Rovann Linhalis, eu quero inserir o id da empresa e a inscrição estadual na tabela de Contas. O select que estou usando é justamente para isso, pois através da inscrição estadual que eu vou ter que inserir. A chave estrangeira que faz o relacionamento na tabela de Contas com a empresa, é através da inscrição estadual. Realizei a correção referente aos campos numéricos, porém foi me apresentado a seguinte mensagem de erro: ORA-02291: restrição de integridade (FK_EMPRESA_CONTAS) violada - chave mãe não localizada

Comment: através do select eu recebo o id da empresa que é vinculado a inscrição estadual. porém ao tentar inserir é apresentado esta mensagem de erro após as correções dos formatos do numeros que você mencionou. ORA-02291: restrição de integridade (FK_EMPRESA_CONTAS) violada - chave mãe não localizada

Comment: agora o problema passou a ser esse campo inscricao_estadual, pela lógica nele deveria ter o número da inscricao e não o ID da empresa. Verifique como está definida a FK.